# Parent click event not running as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following div hierarchy in my page design. I've bound a click event on the bill-item element which has multiple child elements covering the bill-item element.

```
<div class="bill-item">
    <!-- Item image -->
    <div class="bill-item-img"></div>
    <!-- Item description -->
    <div class="bill-item-description">
        <div class="bill-item-name">
            <!-- Item Name -->
            <p class="bill-item-name-left">Normal Cofee</p>
            <!-- Item Price -->
            <p class="bill-item-name-right">170.00</p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Total item price -->
        <div class="bill-item-price">   <span>170.00</span>

        </div>
        <!-- Item Quantity -->
        <div class="bill-item-amount">  <span>1</span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Increas & Decrease item Quantity -->
    <div class="bill-amount-selection"> <a class="amount-increase" href="#"></a>
    <a class="amount-decrease" href="#"></a>

    </div>
    <div class="kot-bot">   <span>-- KOT / BOT --</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

But when I click on the bill-item element the click event doesn't get executed! Can anyone explain me how could I get the event to trigger. This is the method I bound the click event.

```
$('.bill-item-list').on('click', '.bill-item', function(e) {
        var posX = e.pageX;
        var posY = e.pageY;
        showToolTip(posX,posY,this);
    })
```

Comment: add `e.stopPropagation()` before `var posx = e.pageX;`

Comment: [Working as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/VbVGH/) as long as you're assuming that the `<div class="bill-item-list">` is the static parent element you'll be appending new `<div class="bill-item">`'s too. If those two statements are true, can you verify the version of jQuery you're using?

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri if that does not work then try `$(document).on('click', '.bill-item', function(e) {`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy : yeah that's correct but it doesn't get fired in my code! :(

Comment: Are you including a `$(function(){ });` wrapped around your code to ensure it's bound on document ready?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't see a bill-item-list element in your snippet.  Try the following:

```
$('.bill-item').click(function(e) {
    var posX = e.pageX;
    var posY = e.pageY;
    showToolTip(posX, posY, this);
});
```

If bill-item-list is the actual parent of all bill-items, then your approach should work:

```
$('.bill-item-list').on('click', '.bill-item', function(e) {
    var posX = e.pageX;
    var posY = e.pageY;
    showToolTip(posX, posY, this);
});
```